# Exportar uma matriz de dados do matlab para o excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, matlab

Eu tenho um arquivo com várias matrizes, conforme a descrição:

```
Name          Value
lat           <162x168 single>
lon           <162x168 single>
obsData       <162x168x4929 double>
time          <5844x3 double>
v6Data        <162x168x4929 double>
v7Data        <162x168x4929 double>
```

Quero enviar esses dados para o excel ou cvs. Tentei vários comandos sem êxito. Alguém já fez essa exportação?

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Usando o matlab R2015a podes usar esse comando pra salvar matrizes 2D:

```
xlswrite('NomeDoArquivoXLS', matriz);
```

Algumas de suas matrizes possuem 3D. Nesse caso as matrizes podem ser salvas no mesmo arquivo só que em planilhas diferentes. Exemplo:

```
A = zeros(20, 10, 3); 
for i = 1 : size(A,3),
    A(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) + i;
    xlswrite('NomeDoArquivoXLS', A(:,:,i), i); 
end
```

O último parâmetro da função `xlswrite` é o número da planilha.